# How to convert from QNetworkCookieJar to a string dict or requests.cookie?

Tags: python, cookies, pyqt, python-requests, pyqt5

I try to use a QT_WebBrowView to login a website and then use the cookies after login to get the page by requests. So I need convert the QNetworkCookieJar to a string dict or requests.cookie directly. Blow is the relative fragment of code. Is there some function can do so?

Thanks.

Environment: Python 3.4.3 and PyQT5.

```
import requests
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtNetwork

    self.QT_cookiejar_webbrowser = QtNetwork.QNetworkCookieJar()
    self.QT_WebBrowView_wb.page().networkAccessManager().setCookieJar(self.QT_cookiejar_webbrowser)


def get_cookie(self):
    QT_cookies = self.QT_cookiejar_webbrowser.allCookies()
    print("QT_Cookies=%r" % QT_cookies)
    for each_cookie in QT_cookies:
        print("\n\n%r" % each_cookie)
        QtCore.QStringListModel
    # req = requests.get("http://www.baidu.com")
    # req_cookie = req.cookies
    # print("req_cookie=%r" % req_cookie)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some codes at [here](https://gitgud.net/TheScraper/ggscraper/raw/master/ghost2.py). But it only work on Python2 and PyQT4 and can't run alone. I made some change to it to fit for PyQT5 and python3. 
Now you can use it to transform the format of cookie and cookiejar between PyQT and Python. And save into or load from a file in disk. 
If you feel it is useful, pls click the Useful button on the left.  \^o^/

```
from http.cookiejar import Cookie, LWPCookieJar, CookieJar
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDateTime
from PyQt5.QtNetwork import QNetworkCookie, QNetworkCookieJar

class QT5_Py_Cookie(object):
    @staticmethod
    def toQtCookie(PyCookie):
        qc = QNetworkCookie(PyCookie.name, PyCookie.value)
        qc.setSecure(PyCookie.secure)
        if PyCookie.path_specified:
            qc.setPath(PyCookie.path)
        if PyCookie.domain != "":
            qc.setDomain(PyCookie.domain)
        if PyCookie.expires and PyCookie.expires != 0:
            t = QDateTime()
            t.setTime_t(PyCookie.expires)
            qc.setExpirationDate(t)
        # not yet handled(maybe less useful):
        # py cookie.rest / QNetworkCookie.setHttpOnly()
        return qc

    @staticmethod
    def toPyCookie(QtCookie):
        port = None
        port_specified = False
        secure = QtCookie.isSecure()
        name = QtCookie.name().data().decode()
        value = QtCookie.value().data().decode()
        v = QtCookie.path()
        path_specified = bool(v != "")
        path = v if path_specified else None
        v = QtCookie.domain()
        domain_specified = bool(v != "")
        domain = v
        if domain_specified:
            domain_initial_dot = v.startswith('.')
        else:
            domain_initial_dot = None
        v = int(QtCookie.expirationDate().toTime_t())
        expires = 2147483647 if v > 2147483647 else v
        rest = {"HttpOnly": QtCookie.isHttpOnly()}
        discard = False
        return Cookie(
            0,
            name,
            value,
            port,
            port_specified,
            domain,
            domain_specified,
            domain_initial_dot,
            path,
            path_specified,
            secure,
            expires,
            discard,
            None,
            None,
            rest,
        )

    def toPyCookieJar(self, QtCookieJar, PyCookieJar):
        for c in QtCookieJar.allCookies():
            PyCookieJar.set_cookie(self.toPyCookie(c))

    def toQtCookieJar(self, PyCookieJar, QtCookieJar, keep_old=False):
        allCookies = QtCookieJar.allCookies() if keep_old else []
        for pc in PyCookieJar:
            qc = self.toQtCookie(pc)
            allCookies.append(qc)
        QtCookieJar.setAllCookies(allCookies)

    def load_cookies(self, cookie_storage, keep_old=False):
        """load from cookielib's CookieJar or Set-Cookie3 format text file.

        :param cookie_storage: file location string on disk or CookieJar
            instance.
        :param keep_old: Don't reset, keep cookies not overridden.
        """
        cookie_jar = QNetworkCookieJar()
        if cookie_storage.__class__.__name__ == 'str':
            cj = LWPCookieJar(cookie_storage)
            cj.load()
            self.toQtCookieJar(cj, cookie_jar)
        elif cookie_storage.__class__.__name__.endswith('CookieJar'):
            self.toQtCookieJar(cookie_storage, cookie_jar, keep_old)
        else:
            raise ValueError('unsupported cookie_storage type.')
        return cookie_jar

    def save_cookies(self, cookie_storage, cookie_jar):
        """Save to http.cookiejar's CookieJar or Set-Cookie3 format text file.

        :param cookie_storage: file location string or CookieJar instance.
        :param cookie_jar: http.cookiejar's Cookiejar for save.
        """
        if cookie_storage.__class__.__name__ == 'str':
            cj = LWPCookieJar(cookie_storage)
            self.toPyCookieJar(cookie_jar, cj)
            cj.save()
        elif cookie_storage.__class__.__name__.endswith('CookieJar'):
            self.toPyCookieJar(cookie_jar, cookie_storage)
        else:
            raise ValueError('unsupported cookie_storage type.')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
qtNetworkCookies = self.QT_cookiejar_webbrowser.cookiesForUrl(url)
cookies = RequestsCookieJar()
for qtNetworkCookie in qtNetworkCookies:
    cookie = requests.cookies.create_cookie(name=str(qtNetworkCookie.name(), 'utf-8'), value=str(qtNetworkCookie.value(), 'utf-8'))
    cookie.domain = ".google.com"  #your domain
    cookies.set_cookie(cookie)
```

Comment: Please add some explanation... not just a code blurb